# scipy.interpolate.griddata slow due to unnecessary data

Tags: scipy

I have a map with a 600*600 aequidistant x,y grid with associated scalar values.

I have around 1000 x,y coordinates at which I would like to get the bi-linear interpolated map values. Those are randomly placed in an inner center area of the map with around 400*400 size.

I decided to go with the griddata function with method linear. My understanding is that with linear interpolation I would only need the three nearest grid positions around each coordinate do get the well defined interpolated values. So I would require around 3000 data points of the map to perform the interpolation. The 360k data points are highly unnecessary for this task.

Throwing stupidly the complete map in results in long execution times of a half minute. Since it's easy to narrow the map already down to the area of interest I could reduce execution time to nearly 20%.

I am now wondering if I oversaw something in my assumption that I need only the three nearest neighbours for my task. And if not, whether there is a fast solution to filter those 3000 out of the 360k. I assume looping 3000 times over the 360k lines will take longer than to just throw in the inner map.

Edit: I had also a look at the comparison of the result with 600*600 and the reduced data points. I am actually surprised and concerned about the observation, that the interpolation results differ partly significantly.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that RegularGridinterpolator is the way to go for me. It's fast and I have a regular grid already.

I tried to sort out my findings with the differences in interpolation value and found griddata to show unexpected behavior for me.

Check out the issue I created for details.
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/17378